# Reshaping a multidimensional Numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a numpy array of shape `(1429,1)` where each row itself is a numpy array of shape `(3,100`) where l may vary from row to row. 
How can I reshape this array by flattening each row such that the resulting numpy array will have the shape `(1429, 300)`?

Comment: Show us your minimal and verifiable example

Answer (score 2):

I guess your initial array's shape is (1429, 3, 100), if that's true, you can change it's shape as below:

```
import numpy as np
a = a.flatten().reshape((1429, 300))    #a is the initial numpy array
```

Answer (score 2):

The type of your embedding structure is probably `object.`  It's just a collection of references on 1429 `numpy.ndarrays`.

As an exemple :

```
a=np.empty((1429,1),object)
for x in a  :
    x[0]=np.random.rand(3,100)  


In [19]: a.shape,a.dtype
Out[19]: ((1429, 1), dtype('O'))

In [20]: a[0,0].shape
Out[20]: (3, 100)
```

The structure is probably not contiguous. To obtain a block containing all your data, you must reconstruct it to obtain the good layout :

```
b=np.array([x.ravel() for x in a.ravel()])

In [21]: b.shape
Out[21]: (1429, 300)
```

`ravel` discard unwanted dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it is an object dtype array with shape (1429,1), and all elements are 2d of shape (3,100), a good way to 'flatten' is to use `concatenate` or `stack`.

```
np.stack(arr.ravel()).reshape(-1,300)
```

I use `arr.ravel()` so the array looks like a (1429) element list to `stack`.  `stack` then concatenates the elements, creating a (1429, 3, 100) array.  The reshape then converts that to (1429, 300).

```
In [939]: arr = np.empty((5,1),object)
In [940]: arr[:,0] = [np.arange(6).reshape(2,3) for _ in range(5)]
In [941]: arr
Out[941]: 
array([[array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])],
       [array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])],
       [array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])],
       [array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])],
       [array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])]], dtype=object)
In [942]: np.stack(arr.ravel())   
Out[942]: 
array([[[0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5]],

       [[0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5]],

       [[0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5]],

       [[0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5]],

       [[0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5]]])
In [943]: np.stack(arr.ravel()).reshape(-1,6)
Out[943]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])
```

`np.stack` with the default `axis=0` is the same as `np.array(...)`.

Or with `concatenate`

```
In [950]: np.concatenate(arr.ravel(),axis=0)
Out[950]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])
In [951]: np.concatenate(arr.ravel(),axis=0).reshape(5,6)
Out[951]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])
```